# Facebook customer chat get OAuth of logged user

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-customer-chat

I'm building system in which user can sign in into his account with facebook customer chat interface. So I need 2 callbacks from chat to my js:

1. Get OAuth user data to sign in into his account on my site
2. Get message that user wrote

Is it possible with fb customer chat plugin?